# Pip installs packages into the python 3.9 folder, but the executable commands are in the python 3.8

Tags: python, pip, python-3.9

I have both python 3.8 and 3.9 on my Mac. when I install a new package by `pip3 install ...`, the package will go to the python 3.9 folder, but apparently the executable commands to run in terminal is in python 3.8 folder, so even though I installed a package, I cannot run the command lines come with it.

I guess I have to somehow point the path of python to version 3.9?
Can somebody help me to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Try `which python3.9` to definitively determine if and where Python 3.9 lives on your path. Then run `python3.9 -m pip install …` to ensure that the command gets executed against the Python 3.9 interpreter.